# Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol

Tags: browser, text, controls, protocols

I know that the [`Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2324.html) is a **joke**, but is there say a joke ***browser that supports htcpcp?***

Comment: Note also that [IP over avian carriers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149) has [been implemented](http://news.cnet.com/2100-1001-257064.html).

Comment: I want this so I don't have to walk to my coffee pot twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is implemented as an emacs extension available from http://emarsden.chez.com/downloads/ (scroll down to coffee.el)